# Unable to add eth0:0 in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ethernet

I have Ubuntu 12.04.1 and am trying to configure an ethernet interface alias `eth0:0`.

Here is my `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
pre-up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.up.rules

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.0.1
gateway 192.168.0.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.0.0
broadcast 192.168.0.255

auto eth0:0
iface eth0:0 inet static
address 192.168.1.1
gateway 192.168.1.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.1.0
broadcast 192.168.1.255
```

If I reboot, the system starts with message: `Starting with partial network configuration`, and `eth0` configured only.

I've tried

- Removing `pre-up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.up.rules`
- Changing the netmask of `eth0:0` to `255.255.0.0`
- Changing the gateway of `eth0:0` to `192.168.0.1`

"ifup" fails like this:

```
$ sudo ifup eth0:0
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Failed to bring up eth0:0.
```

`service networking restart` never works (even before I added `eth0:0`):

```
$ sudo service networking restart
stop: Unknown instance: 
networking stop/waiting
```

Unfortunately after the commands I even don't see updates in `/var/log/syslog` or `/var/log/dmsg`.

Output of ifconfig:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1e:33:71:cd:a4  
          inet addr:192.168.0.1  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:45 Base address:0x4000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:3248 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3248 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:279379 (279.3 KB)  TX bytes:279379 (279.3 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:11:22:33:44:55  
          inet addr:78.225.121.83  Bcast:78.225.121.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::211:22ff:fe33:4455/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:37801 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:39871 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:36003811 (36.0 MB)  TX bytes:7490816 (7.4 MB)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: can you still manually configure eth0:0?

Comment: What's the output of `sudo ifconfig`?

Comment: I added output of ifconfig :)

Comment: You have a mistake in your configuration: The IP address you've assigned for `eth0:0` is not within the same subnet as `eth0`. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: In reality I try to create different interfaces for different networks, because sometime I move from place to place... So what can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Is the broadcast `192.168.0.255` correct for `eth0:0`, or should it be `192.168.1.255`?

Comment: Thank you for response. I tried with right broadcast, same result...